# I am getting segmentation fault for merge sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I have been programming for quite sometime. But I don't know much about algorithms. Now I have decided to learn some algorithms. I am learning merge-sort. I am learning from the Coreman book. This is the code that I have written.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int infinity = 1000;

void merge_sort(int A[],int p, int r);
void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r);

int main()
{
  freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
  freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int A[n];
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {
    cin >> A[i];
  }
  merge_sort(A,0,n);
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {
    cout << A[i] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}

void merge_sort(int A[],int p, int r)
{
  if(p<r)
  {

    int q = (r-p)/2;
    merge_sort(A,p,q);
    merge_sort(A,q,r);
    merge(A,p,q,r);
  }
  return;
}

void merge(int A[], int p, int q, int r)
{
  int n1 = q-p;
  int n2 = r-q;
  int L[n1+1], R[n2+1];
  for(int i=0; i<n1; ++i)
  {
    L[i] = A[p+i];
  }
  for(int i=0; i<n2; ++i)
  {
    R[i] = A[q+i];
  }
  L[n1] = R[n2] = infinity;
  for(int i=0; i<=n1; ++i)
  {
    cout << L[i] << endl;
  }

  for(int j=0; j<=n2; ++j)
  {
    cout << R[j] << endl;
  }
  for(int i=0, j=0, k=p; k<r; ++k)
  {
    if(L[i] <= R[j])
    {
      A[k] = L[i];
      ++i;
    }
    else
    {
      A[k] = R[j];
      ++j;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

But I am getting segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: I don't know what that is. I usually code in PHP, for websites.

Comment: @eddard.stark Then this is a good opportunity to find out.

Comment: If you use linux, gdb is a good choice.

Comment: In short: It's a tool, that let's you step through your code step-by-step, making it easier to spot bugs.

Comment: Let me check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a way to go on Linux:

1. Compile your program with debug info (`g++ -g merger_sort.cpp -o merger_sort`)
2. Load it in debuger: `>>> gdb merge_sort`
3. Run it: `(gdb) run`.

You will see:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400b1e in merge_sort (A=0x7ffffffddda0, p=0, r=1)
```

4. look at the position in the code: `(gdb) layout src`
5. look at the backtrace: `(gdb) bt`

It is pretty long... So you have a stack overflow:) USe debugger too see why.